# Map Matching between two geometry (line string)

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis-2.0

I have two tables in PostGIS, both having line string as the geometry type.  I wanted to extract a similar or exact matching street. Can you please suggest query or algorithm for it?

```
Table 1

column name(Id Geom1) data(1 0102000020E610000002000000590E3EDEF5AB23409255B6B4BF1B4A4031197DBBDBAB23404AF663EEB51B4A40)


Table 2

column name(Id Geom2) data(1  10102000020E61000000300000057900B73277D2340A1675831011E4A4094C55801197D23406A204C40021E4A40B0CFF7AE9C7C234079AAE8B4131E4A40)
```

I have tired ST_HausdorffDistance(table1.Geom1, table2.Geom2)

but not able to get the desired result, my dataset is big, table one has 2370 record and table two 23125 records.

Can you please some effective way to do map matching in Python or Using SQL in Postgis.